# CWE-326 on FIPS compliant AES256

Tags: c#, veracode

Why does Veracode flag the following FIPS compliant C#?

```
var cipher = new AesCng()
{
  BlockSize = 128,
  KeySize = 256,
  Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
  Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
};
```

Comment: Because it was programmed to. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: To mitigate a security risk it must be understood sufficiently to make a correction.  I need to understand why AesCng presents a violation of CWE-326.  Is it because AES256 is no longer considered secure enough, is it one of the FIPS settings, or is there a setting missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi: current Veracode scans likely wouldn't flag CWE 326 on a use of AES with a key size of 256. If this was a recent scan, could you please reach out to Veracode Support so we can take a closer look to find out why this was flagged?

If this was a result from an older scan, you may want to try rescanning the application to see if the issue is still flagged.

Comment: This code is flagged as a current flaw.  I tried to call support but they wouldn't talk with me.  They want to schedule a 'consultation' for next week.

Comment: The consultant tells me he believes this is a known false positive that will likely be fixed in the next release.